# How to determine if we need to learn another javascript library?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, extjs

I was learning jQuery and am still learning it. And then heard about extjs. extjs has its own ways of doing similiar things in jQuery and i dont feel i can remember both at one time. My Question is should i be learning about as many libraries as they evolve or should i just concentrate on one and be deprived of extra features the new one is introducing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using both, ExtJS for full web apps (RIAs) and jQuery for web site enhancements.

I tried using ExtCore (the LGPL part of ExtJS, limited to dom queries, animations, ... It's not as usable as jQuery.

But I wouldn't try building a RIA with jQuery.

And ExtJS4 will be awesome (but this is another subject).

So, to answer your question, yes you can learn both, the fundamentals are quite the same, features are quite different, and remember : they are framework for the same language and environment, I mean javascript and Browser.

Comment: thanks for explaining what i was wondering is i am also interested in learing extjs RIA. So where should i start and i want to cut short LGPL part. I think jQuery is good enough for that.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that jquery and extjs are not perfect substitutes and both have their place, at least right now

Comment: Why not use ExtJs for the interface and JQuery for the DOM manipulations? In ExtJS you can choose if you want ExtCore, JQuery, prototype or something else to your liking. Best of both worlds!

Answer (score 3):

if it is for business you can use PETS:

### P = ( E - T ) * $ * .80

where

- *P* = the profit.
- *E* = is the efficiency gain in total HOURS (IE, the time gained on projects when mastering the new technique)
- *T* = the time spent on training and learning in HOURS (included during productivity hours)
- *$* = your hourly rate (eg: $60,-)
- *.80* is the constant that I personally put in since the techniques are always evolving, that is, you can always be one step behind.

so

## (300 - 200) * $60,- * .80 --> $4800

you have a profit of 4800 dollars when you master a new library in 5 full working weeks and gain an rough hour a day trough a year.

that is if the library has an added value ;)

Comment: I wish I could favorite answers.

Comment: Thanks ;) But I forgot to mention the books or training costs... if there are any needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should decide which one you will be using - you will likely be using only one at time anyways. The libraries often have compatibility modes, but I don't think there is a reason to use two on one page.

Comment: We recdently used two libraries mootools and jQuery together for one having some extra features over other. People say extjs have wonderful grid and desktop like ui. what if we may need both?